# ollydbg entry point changes after run

Tags: entry-point, ollydbg

I have been following a lot of tutorials on how to use ollydbg, but I have a problem that seems to be consistent across different executables.

The entry point seems to be "crap", but changes after the initial run. This makes it extremely hard to debug things that are decided at the start of a program.

As you can see in the screenshot, the author of the tutorial does not have this problem.

I have tried running different versions of ollydbg (1.1 and 2.0), and used different configs. I have also tried a different computer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what tutorials you're following, but if the entry point is changing, it is possibly a protection mechanism. Check out Lena151 Reversing Tutorial #1-5, they explain a lot of simple fixes to problems like this. You can download them from here:
http://tuts4you.com/download.php?list.17